# Cannot connect to MongoDB - Authentication Failed

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Having an issue connecting to MongoDB when starting a new MERN stack project:

server.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true  });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

.env file:

```
ATLAS_URI = mongodb+srv://exampleUser:exampleUserPassword@cluster0.y9bpc.mongodb.net/example- 
database?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

receiving error:

```
(node:23036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, was just following a tutorial. Only difference from the tutorial is the connection string which also requires a dbname which I created and added. I'm hoping it's something more simple than that. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that I chose to add my own IP address instead of allowing access from anywhere and that was the issue. Hooray!